# Can i access aide android sdk installation path?

Tags: android, sdk, aide-ide

i have some problems using default sdk icons where i get `"recource not found" errors` for definitions as `"@android:drawable/ic_action_delete"`.
 ***I want to check the resource names from the `sdk` folder***. Is it possible to access the `sdk` installation folder which is used by `aide-ide` on a android mobile phone which is not rooted?

Comment: go to Windows->Prefrences->Android and there you can find the base path of your sdk folder

Comment: can you give your xml code where u are using that

Comment: I am not on a windows machine. I am developing on the phone itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if some of the icons are stored in the device, most of them are nor public. You cannot use them directly with the code. Even when you use them, they are not guaranteed to be in all the phones in the market.

What you should do instead is to copy those resources into your projects' drawable folders.

You can download all the latest drawable assets from Google's public repository. 
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Comment: Sorry for the late approval but i am surprised that so did not send me any notifications for this answer.

Comment: Although i was expecting this answer i asked the question for a hope that there would be a better approach without copying anything. But i can see tradeoffs such as portability.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way. :(